# how to compare the time and date using mysql and c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a table `logout`  with columns

```
logout_id
logout_datetime  values format like this(2011-09-08 11:09:09)
```

and i want to compare the logout_datetime with today date and time also....

for that i have done like this....

```
string dtStartString = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string timeonly = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

string sql = @"select logout_id"; 
sql+= string.Format("where logout_datetime = '{0}'",dtStartString );
```

but it will compares only date in `logoutdatetime` ,its wrong i want to compare the time also

how can i do this..

would any one pls help on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course your code is only comparing the date because you are passing only `dtStartString` which does **not** have a time part.

try to pass this:

```
string dtStartString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: it it indented to have **2** spaces instead of 1 between dd and HH?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Parameters`.

```
string sql = "select logout_id from TableName 
                  where logout_datetime=@logout_datetime";
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@logout_datetime",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Datetime)
                   .Value=DateTime.Now; // you may assign any value of DateTime  type.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [date-format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), or [extract](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function.

You should read more about [date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)